# How to generate a md5 checksum for a CSV file in JSP

Tags: jsp, csv, md5, checksum

I need to calculate the checksum of a csv file.  The checksum will change every time the data in the file is changed.  I found nothing useful over the internet in this regard.

Comment: Google tells the answer, read : http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=216274 . You can easily replace CRC32 with MD5 .

Comment: @ShivanRaptor You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Zoot: this is not the correct answer though. CheckedInputStream doesn't support MD5.

Comment: @BalusC I'm still OK with Shivan's comment being an answer, because then you could downvote/make that comment in Shivan's answer rather than the question comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this problem is not specific to JSP. JSP is just a HTML code generator. Writing Java code in a JSP file instead of a normal Java class doesn't make it a JSP problem. You would help yourself more if you concentrate on solving future Java problems using the "Java" keyword, not using the "JSP" keyword.

Said that, you can just use [`MessageDigest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) which you update with the bytes read from the file.

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file.csv");
MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];

for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
    md5.update(buffer, 0, length);
}     

byte[] hash = digest.digest();
```

You may want to convert the hash to hex afterwards.

```
StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hash.length * 2);

for (byte b : hash) {
    if ((b & 0xff) < 0x10) {
        hex.append("0");
    }

    hex.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
}

String hexString = hex.toString();
```