# Can I read and write to a csv file simultaneously?

Tags: php, magento, csv, file-io

I want to read a **csv** file from top to bottom every time in a for each loop and check if the same content already exists, overwrites it with new content. For example, if the product id is the same, overwrites old data with new data in the same row.

Right now, I'm using **fgetcsv** to read the **csv** file line by line. Is there a method to write to the same line as I read the **csv**?

Comment: screams, use a db not flat csv file, to me

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a method to write to the same line as I read the csv?

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Yes, but it's massively difficult and generally you would simply want to completely rewrite the file from start to finish.

Let's say you have a file containing:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

and you wants to alter `jumped` to `jumps`. "Easy!" you might think, "I'll just change out the words". You look up file IO and how to move pointers around, seek to the position of the beginning of the word "jumped" and write "jumps". Now you have:

```
The quick brown fox jumpsd over the lazy dog.
```

Uh oh, that's not right. We'll need to delete that errant `d`. How? By shifting every single byte in the file up by one byte. A tedious operation and a great way to corrupt your data due to small oversights and odd corner cases. [1 to 3 byte UTF characters? BOMs?] You're in even more trouble if you need to insert a word *longer* than the original `jumped`.

Think of files like brick walls. It's easy to append a new row of bricks to the top of the wall, but if you want to stick even one extra brick into the middle you might as well just knock the whole thing down and rebuild.

If you have set of data that needs to be modified in-place then just about the worst place to store it is in flat files like CSV or XML files. Go with Dagon's suggestion and put that data in a database where it belongs.

Don't have a DB server? Look into [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/).

Comment: Hi, I took your advice and loaded all the data I need in a mysql database table. How do I check if the same item exists in the table, if so rewrite the row. If not, append to table? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

forgetting about your implementation here, you are asking the fastest way to check if a file has changed in a loop. I though first checksum might be reasonable but it might be a bit longer than you thought. 
[How to generate a md5 checksum for a CSV file in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795749/how-to-generate-a-md5-checksum-for-a-csv-file-in-jsp)

the next option is to use file.GetlastWriteTime(). Skip the loop and just check if it is the same as the last time it was used. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime(v=vs.100).aspx

woops... didn't notice you are using PHP. I am sure there is a similar method for both of those options out there.

Comment: Im not asking to check if a file is changed in a loop. I wanna run a check in an existing csv file.